Show that $f(x) = x^3 - 6x$ has no minimum on $[0,2]_{\mathbb{Q}}$.
I am doing Exercise 2.3.2 in Tom Lindstrom's real analysis book Spaces. It reads

Show that the function $f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ defined by $f(x) = x^3 - 6x$ is continuous at all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, but that it does not have a minimum in $[0,2]_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Compare to the Extreme Value Theorem. (We define $[a,b]_{\mathbb{Q}} := \{x \in \mathbb{Q} : a \leq x \leq b\}$.)

We know that $f$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ since it is a polynomial, so $f$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{Q}$. I am having trouble with the next part though.
By looking at the function on $\mathbb{R}$ and using the Closed Interval Method (sort of cheating here to gain some insight), we can check that the minimum of the function on the interval $[0, 2]$ in fact occurs at $\sqrt{2}$ which of course is not in $\mathbb{Q}$, so we know that the function won't have a minimum on $[0, 2]_{\mathbb{Q}}$ since we may get infinitely close to $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Now, I am trying to prove it rigorously using the tools I have up to this point in the book (sequences, continuity, supremum, infimum, etc.) without using differentiability.
I was originally trying to go by contradiction. Suppose that $f$ achieves its maximum on $[0, 2]_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Then, there exists $m \in [0, 2]_{\mathbb{Q}}$ such that $f(m) \leq f(x)$ for any $x \in [0, 2]_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Then, letting $S := \{f(x) : x \in [0, 2]_{\mathbb{Q}}\}$, we have $f(m) = \inf S$. Then, I was hoping to contradict that this is the infimum possibly using the $\varepsilon$ criteria (not sure how this would use the fact that $m$ is rational though).
The other option would be to proceed directly, showing that for any $m \in [0, 2]_{\mathbb{Q}}$, there exists $n \in [0, 2]_{\mathbb{Q}}$ such that $f(n) \leq f(m)$ (perhaps using the Archimedean property).
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, my apologies if anything looks weird in the text. It was rendering oddly on my screen, but I believe everything is typed correctly.

The min over the reals is attained at an irrational number. There are rationals arbitrarily close to this irrational. By continuity there are $f(r)$, $r$ rational arbitrarily close to the min. Since the function is not constant in any interval, the values $f(r)$ are all larger than the min value.

It turns out that I actually had access to the lemma forming the basis for the closed interval method, but I missed it in the book. It was given as Lemma 2.3.5: Assume that $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ has a maximum or minimum at an inner point $c \in (a, b)$ where the function is differentiable. Then, $f'(c) = 0$. This actually streamlines the solution a lot. Anne Bauval's answer sort of alludes to the proof of this lemma, and pieces of her answer still appear in the solution.

If $f$ restricted to $[0,2]_{\Bbb Q}$
had a minimum at $m$, first note that $m$ would be strictly between $0$ and $2$ (compare $f(0)$ and $f(2)$ with, for instance, $f(1)$). Then, for every $x\in[0,2]_{\Bbb Q}$, the quotient
$$\frac{f(x)-f(m)}{x-m}=x^2+mx+m^2-6$$ would be $\ge0$ if $x> m$, and $\le0$ if $x< m$, hence (by continuity on $\Bbb R$) this polynomial would be $0$ at $x=m$, i.e.
$$m^2=2,$$
which is impossible since $\sqrt2$ is irrational.

Thanks for the reply! In the denominator of the fraction, did you mean x - m instead of x = m?

Yes thank you, fixed.

I tried to recreate this myself, and I almost have a full grasp on it. I am a little confused about why $\frac{f(x) - f(m)}{x - m} \geq 0$ if $x > m$ and vice-versa is sufficient. If we could say that the difference quotient is strictly greater than (less than) $0$, I see the conclusion. Why does non-negative and non-positive suffice here?

Let $P(x)=x^2+mx+m^2-6$. There exists $x_-<m<x_+$ arbitrarily close to $m$ s.t. $P(x_+)\ge0$ and $P(x_-)\le0$. Hence $P(m)=\lim_{m^+}P\ge0$ and $P(m)=\lim_{m^-}P\le0$. Thank you for your remark. IVT was actually not used, I'll remove it.

That makes sense! Let me work it out myself, and I’ll accept the solution. Thanks so much!
